# passwd file deleted in ubuntu

Tags: passwd-file

i was recently making some researches about the passwd file, and out of curiosity i deleted it, after i deleted it my computer froze, and after a hard reboot it doesnt boot. i found a solution on this site but it had to do with restoring a backup of the deleted file.
so on my own accord i ran a live-cd and copied passwd- as the new passwd file, now the computer boots to the login screen but the screen keeps flicking with a black boot screen.

please i need your help, i have several works on hold for the past 2 days.

thank you.

p.s i am using ubuntu 13.04

Comment: I can't really imagine a missing passwd file resulting in the symptoms you describe. I'd look into alternative causes as well.

Comment: my problem actually started immediately i deleted the passwd file, but i will appreciate it if you had any suggestions on my problem. thank you

Answer (score 1):

There should have been a recent backup of your original passwd file at `/var/backups/passwd.bak`

Try booting from the live CD again and copying that file, instead of the one from the live CD. For example, if you have mounted the old filesystem at /mnt/oldsys then

```
sudo cp /mnt/oldsys/var/backups/passwd.bak /mnt/oldsys/etc/passwd
```

It will be slightly more complicated if your old system has a separate /var partition, but basically the same process. Then make sure the permissions on the copied file are correct

```
sudo chmod 644 /mnt/oldsys/etc/passwd
```

Comment: i tried the solution you suggested, i copied the the backup of the passwd file (passwd.bak), but i still had no response, so i copied the passwd.bak as passwd thinking the .bak extension was stopping it from being read. this time around i had a response but the same as when i copied the passwd- file. thank you

Comment: You may need to re-set the permissions on the copied file (they should be -rw-r--r--) - see my edit about `chmod`

Comment: can you please give me a link to your edit on chmod, for now i ran sudo chmod -rw-r--r-- passwd, but it still did not work. thank you so much for your responses, i really appreciate them. i am grateful